Angle perturbation due to error in vectors
INTRODUCTION: I am given 3 points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$ all with corresponding error margins $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \epsilon_3$ where the 2-norm of all of them is bounded by some constant $\epsilon$ that I know. Also, the true points (that I don't know) lie somewhere in the error regions. I create 2 vectors $v'_1, v'_2$ as follows:
$ 
v'_1 = (x_1 - x_2, y_1 - y_2), \\
v'_2 = (x_3 - x_2, y_3 - y_2)
$
Lets say the true angle (the angle between the true vectors) is $\theta$ and I know it, and the angle between the vectors $v'_1, v'_2$ is $\theta'$. Also, let $v_1, v_2$ be the true vectors defined in a similar way as $v'_1, v'_2$, but for the actual points that are unknown for me.
PROBLEM: I want to know whether it is possible to achieve the true angle, i.e., I want to bound the difference $|\theta - \theta'|$ in terms of my vectors $v'_1, v'_2$ and $\epsilon $ and then see if the difference in angles is contained in that bound. False Positive can happen, False Negatives can't.
PROGRESS: The following is a bound that seems to me to be correct, but is derived via drawings and observation

And this is the bound (of the cosine of the angles) derived rigorously and it is not here for you to analyze it, but to give the idea of the path that I was taking:

QUESTION: The bound that I got rigorously is not very tight and give large errors, I don't know if that's because I made an error somewhere, or if I took the wrong path. I would like to get suggestions on how to proceed forwards to get a better upper bound rigorously. Moreover, if anyone knows how to get the bound in term of $arcsin$ rigorously (in a similar manner as my second bound) that would also be appreciated. In general, if you have any experience with this or suggestions how to proceed, please share with me.
